# Discord music bot not reading the command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So, I'm trying to make a discord music bot and I keep getting this one error whenever I use the play command I think its not loading the cog or has something to do with that. this is my main function

and this is my command inside my music_player class[the error that I'm getting once I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUC8f.png)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("!"),
    description='Relatively simple music bot example',
    intents=intents,
)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})')
    print('------')


bot.add_cog("cogs.music_player")
```

**music_player.py**

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

class music_player(commands.Cog):
    
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

        # Checks whether the song is playing or not
        self.isplaying = False
        self.ispaused = False


        # The music queue ( this contains the song and the channel)
        self.musicque = []


        # The code below is taken from github to get the best quality of sound possible
        self.ytdl_format_options = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
        'restrictfilenames': True,
        'noplaylist': True,
        'nocheckcertificate': True,
        'ignoreerrors': False,
        'logtostderr': False,
        'quiet': True,
        'no_warnings': True,
        'default_search': 'auto',
        'source_address': '0.0.0.0',  # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
    }
                           
        self.ffmpeg_options = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

        self.vc = None

    # This small function searches a song on youtube
    def search_yt(self, song):

            # with youtube open as
            with YoutubeDL(self.ytdl_format_options) as ydl:

                # This will basically search youtube and return the entries we get from our search 
                try: 
                    info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % song, download=False)['entries'][0]
                except Exception: 
                    return False
            # Returns the info as source
            return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}
    
    def play_next(self):
        if len(self.musicque) > 0:
            self.isplaying = True

            # Get the link of the first song in the que as we did in the play song function
            music_link = self.musicque[0][0]['source']

            # Remove the song currently playing same way we did in the play_song function
            self.musicque.pop(0)

            # same lambda function we used the play_song function
            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(music_link, **self.ffmpeg_options), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.isplaying = False
    
    async def play_song(self, ctx):
        if len(self.musicque) > 0:
            self.isplaying = True

            # Get the link of the first song in the que
            music_link = self.musicque[0][0]['source']

            # Connect to the voice channel the user is currently in if bot is not already connected
            if self.vc == None or not self.vc.is_connected():
                self.vc = await self.musicque[0][1].connect()

                # if we fail to connect to the vc for whatever reason
                if self.vc == None:
                    await ctx.send("Could not connect to the voice channel")
                    return
            # Else if the bot is already in voice
            else:
                await self.vc.move_to(self.musicque[0][1])
            
            # Remove the first song in the que using the built in pop function in python as we're already playing the song
            self.musicque.pop(0)

            # Took this lambda play function from github
            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(music_link, **self.ffmpeg_options), after=lambda e: self.next_song())

            """WENT AHEAD AND MOVED NEXT_SONG FUNCTION ABOVE AS I REALIZED IT WOULD NOT WORK IF IT WAS BELOW"""

            """ALL THE FUNCTIONS WE NEEDED FOR OUR COMMANDS TO FUNCTION HAVE BEEN DEFINED NOW ONTO THE COMMAND"""

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, args):

        # This is the song that the user will search and we will look up 
           using the yt-search function that we made earlier
        query = " ".join(args)

        # If user is not in the voice channel
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice_channel
        if voice_channel is None:
            await ctx.send("You're not in a voice channel you dummy")
        # If any song in the que is currently paused resume it
        elif self.ispaused == True:
            self.vc.resume()
        
        else:
            # assign song to the search result of the youtube song
            song = self.search_yt(query)

            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("Incorrect format of song could not play")

            else:
                await ctx.send("Song added")
                self.musicque.append([song, voice_channel])

                if self.isplaying == False:
                    await self.play_song(ctx)




I was expecting the program to play a song or atleast join thet voice channel but apparently it says the command is not found I've tried changing stuff with the cog but it didn't help so I'm fully lost at what I'm doing wrong.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [add_cog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=add_cog#discord.ext.commands.Bot.add_cog) method doesn't work that way; it takes a cog class as an argument, not the path to the cog file. That's the [load_extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=load_extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension)'s job. The `load_extension` will go to the given path and call the `setup` function inside the file, and you have to add the cog inside that setup function. For example:

**cogs/cog_file.py**

```py
class ACogClass(discord.ext.commands.Cog):
    ...
 
async def setup(bot: discord.ext.commands.Bot): # as of discord.py 2, the "setup" function needs to be an async function
    bot.add_cog(ACogClass(bot))
```

**main.py**

```py
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(...)
 
async def setup_hook():
    await bot.load_extension("cogs.cog_file") # as of discord.py 2, the "load_extension" method is now an async function
 
bot.setup_hook = setup_hook # set the bot's default "setup_hook" to our custom "setup_hook"
```